# Marker dragging doesn't work on google maps v3 using java script. How to do it?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

This is the code that I am using to drop a marker after searching for an address and then dragging it.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google AJAX Local Search API + Maps API v3 demo</title>
    <link href="http://www.google.com/uds/css/gsearch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="./places.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/uds/api?file=uds.js&amp;v=1.0&amp;key=ABQIAAAAjU0EJWnWPMv7oQ-jjS7dYxQ82LsCgTSsdpNEnBsExtoeJv4cdBSUkiLH6ntmAr_5O4EfjDwOa0oZBQ" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    // Our global state
    var gLocalSearch;
    var gMap;
    var gInfoWindow;
    var gSelectedResults = [];
    var gCurrentResults = [];
    var gSearchForm;

    // Create our "tiny" marker icon
    var gYellowIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
      "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png",
      new google.maps.Size(12, 20),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      new google.maps.Point(6, 20));
    var gRedIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
      "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png",
      new google.maps.Size(12, 20),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      new google.maps.Point(6, 20));
    var gSmallShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
      "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png",
      new google.maps.Size(22, 20),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      new google.maps.Point(6, 20));

     // Set up the map and the local searcher.
    function OnLoad() {

      // Initialize the map with default UI.
      gMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      // Create one InfoWindow to open when a marker is clicked.
      gInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
      google.maps.event.addListener(gInfoWindow, 'closeclick', function() {
        unselectMarkers();
      });

      // Initialize the local searcher
      gLocalSearch = new GlocalSearch();
      gLocalSearch.setSearchCompleteCallback(null, OnLocalSearch);
    }

    function unselectMarkers() {
      for (var i = 0; i < gCurrentResults.length; i++) {
        gCurrentResults[i].unselect();
      }
    }

    function doSearch() {
      var query = document.getElementById("queryInput").value;
      gLocalSearch.setCenterPoint(gMap.getCenter());
      gLocalSearch.execute(query);
    }

    // Called when Local Search results are returned, we clear the old
    // results and load the new ones.
    function OnLocalSearch() {
      if (!gLocalSearch.results) return;
      var searchWell = document.getElementById("searchwell");

      // Clear the map and the old search well
      searchWell.innerHTML = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < gCurrentResults.length; i++) {
        gCurrentResults[i].marker().setMap(null);
      }
      // Close the infowindow
      gInfoWindow.close();

      gCurrentResults = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < gLocalSearch.results.length; i++) {
        gCurrentResults.push(new LocalResult(gLocalSearch.results[i]));
      }

      var attribution = gLocalSearch.getAttribution();
      if (attribution) {
        document.getElementById("searchwell").appendChild(attribution);
      }

      // Move the map to the first result
      var first = gLocalSearch.results[0];
      gMap.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(first.lat),
                                            parseFloat(first.lng)));

    }

    // Cancel the form submission, executing an AJAX Search API search.
    function CaptureForm(searchForm) {
      gLocalSearch.execute(searchForm.input.value);
      return false;
    }



    // A class representing a single Local Search result returned by the
    // Google AJAX Search API.
    function LocalResult(result) {
      var me = this;
      me.result_ = result;
      me.resultNode_ = me.node();
      me.marker_ = me.marker();
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(me.resultNode_, 'mouseover', function() {
        // Highlight the marker and result icon when the result is
        // mouseovered.  Do not remove any other highlighting at this time.
        me.highlight(true);
      });
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(me.resultNode_, 'mouseout', function() {
        // Remove highlighting unless this marker is selected (the info
        // window is open).
        if (!me.selected_) me.highlight(false);
      });
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(me.resultNode_, 'click', function() {
        me.select();
      });
      document.getElementById("searchwell").appendChild(me.resultNode_);
    }

    LocalResult.prototype.node = function() {
      if (this.resultNode_) return this.resultNode_;
      return this.html();
    };

function geocodePosition(pos) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos
  }, function(responses) {
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
      updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
      updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
    }
  });
}

    // Returns the GMap marker for this result, creating it with the given
    // icon if it has not already been created.
    LocalResult.prototype.marker = function() {
      var me = this;
      if (me.marker_) return me.marker_;
      var marker = me.marker_ = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(me.result_.lat),
                                         parseFloat(me.result_.lng)),
        icon: gYellowIcon, shadow: gSmallShadow, map: gMap});
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        me.select();
      });



  // Add dragging event listeners.
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {

  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {

    updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {

    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
  });

      return marker;
    };

    // Unselect any selected markers and then highlight this result and
    // display the info window on it.
    LocalResult.prototype.select = function() {
      unselectMarkers();
      this.selected_ = true;
      this.highlight(true);
      gInfoWindow.setContent(this.html(true));
      gInfoWindow.open(gMap, this.marker());
    };

    LocalResult.prototype.isSelected = function() {
      return this.selected_;
    };

    // Remove any highlighting on this result.
    LocalResult.prototype.unselect = function() {
      this.selected_ = false;
      this.highlight(false);
    };

    // Returns the HTML we display for a result before it has been "saved"
    LocalResult.prototype.html = function() {
      var me = this;
      var container = document.createElement("div");
      container.className = "unselected";
      container.appendChild(me.result_.html.cloneNode(true));
      return container;
    }

    LocalResult.prototype.highlight = function(highlight) {
      this.marker().setOptions({icon: highlight ? gRedIcon : gYellowIcon});
      this.node().className = "unselected" + (highlight ? " red" : "");
    }


    GSearch.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
    //]]>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
    <p>Perform a local search on the map below:</p>
    <div style="width: 500px;">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
        <div>
          <input type="text" id="queryInput" value="pizza" style="width: 250px;"/>
          <input type="button" value="Find" onclick="doSearch()"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="position: absolute; left: 540px;">
        <div id="searchwell"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="map" style="height: 350px; border: 1px solid #979797;"></div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

But the dragging of the marker doesn't work. How to make it work? This code is obviously taken from google samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default markers are not draggable. You must set the **`draggable`**-option of the marker(s) to true.

Comment: Also, having the console open can break it. When testing, keep the console closed to see results and reopen it, the refresh to see logs. This sucks, but it is better than pulling your hair out for no reason.